# keep parked domain url after click

Tags: .htaccess, url, redirect, dns, hosting

i have a domain `cccc.com` and a parked domain `vvvv.com` in this server

`vvvv.com` root directory is in `cccc.com/v`

everything is fine but when users click in every link in vvvv.com url change to for example `cccc.com/v/?page_id=471`  however i don't want to change address to `cccc.com` !

how can i keep `vvvv.com` url  in all pages and don't allow to change to `cccc.com/v` ?

Comment: Post your existing `.htaccess`

Comment: i dont use any htaccess on my root directory